# BLE multiple connections

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to create a mobile app using flutter that connects and reads/writes data from multiple Bluetooth low energy devices. I am a beginner in flutter and I have read that using BluetoothGatt you can achieve that but I haven't found any exhaustive documentation on the steps I should follow.

Comment: Which BLE library are you using? This should be possible using [flutter_reactive_ble](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble)

Comment: I am using flutter reactive ble but as I said I am new to flutter so I do not have much sense of what I am doing or should do

Comment: [this](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/94) issue explains that you can simply open multiple connections without closing them. Maybe start with the example you can find in the repository and start connecting to one device

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a UI framework.
If the main purpose of your app involves BLE, controlling it from flutter would cause you a headache.

Build your app where all the BLE logic is on the native side, and use the Native bridge as an interface for sending/receiving data to/from the UI.
(You can build it as a plugin, but it's more advanced stuff)

You'll benefit a simple multiplatform unified UI, with all advantages of working natively and having full control over the hardware-related stuff.